# Generating a REST server from hyperledger fabric composer

Tags: server, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Im using the hyperleger fabric as business network and every commands done correctly.but when need to generating a REST server (create the REST API) run the command :

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/EHRUsingBlockchain-master/healthcare$ **composer-rest-server**

but i get this error :

```
 /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server 
 /node_modules/formdata-node/lib/cjs/Blob.js:80
 for await (const chunk of (0, blobHelpers_1.consumeBlobParts)  
 (__classPrivateFieldGet(this, _Blob_parts, "f"))) {
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/formdata-node/lib/cjs/File.js:16:16)
```

how can fix it ... Thank you

Comment: Looks like the code needs support for async iterators, node 8 doesn't have that capability. Node 10 introduced that support. It might fix this problem and break elsewhere of course.

Comment: Thank you @NikKlassen for your response. i changed node version to 10,12 and get same error but  i solved this error using next commands:/ 
**$ npm i -g composer-rest-server** ... after that run 
**$ cd /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server**.... then 
**$ npm install swagger-client@3.9.0** ....Finally run 
**$ rm -rf node_modules/g11n-pipeline/node_modules/swagger-client**....
After that its worked correctly

Comment: Thank you @mohammedalzuharey for the solution. It worked.

Can you please point out the direction where you looked in for solving this issue i.e how did you know it was an issue related to swagger-client?